# module for html to file caching

Tags: node.js, caching, express

Is there module for html to file caching. For example every time on request url `/abc` it searchs file `/abc` in `cache` folder and if found read it to string var and then

```
res.send (htmlFromCache);
```

And on every request end it write html to `cache` folder. So hard pages can be loaded only one time and then load fast from file cache.

Comment: i believe express handles this by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What express does by default is caching the rendering function for a given view template (if you are passing `NODE_ENV=production`, of course). I know a module that may help you improve your web site performance by adding etags to dynamically generated content.

Have a look at this module: https://github.com/lloyd/connect-etagify

There is also this article available https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/02/fantastic-front-end-performance-in-node-part-2-a-node-js-holiday-season-part-6/ where you will find a much deeper explanation and wether this fits your use case or not!